# RVM won't install JRuby, gets exception

Tags: jruby, rvm

So, I have rvm installed on my machine, and I type:

```
rvm install jruby
```

Everything looks good at first, but eventually I get:

```
    jruby-1.5.6 - #fetching 
jruby-1.5.6 - #extracted to /home/jenny/.rvm/src/jruby-1.5.6 (already extracted)
Building Nailgun
jruby-1.5.6 - #installing to /home/jenny/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.5.6
jruby-1.5.6 - #importing default gemsets (/home/jenny/.rvm/gemsets/)
Copying across included gems
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jruby.Main
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.Main not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.9)
jenny@linux-auvv:~/workspace/pcms_stable>
```

I have absolutly no context for debugging this... I honestly have no idea what to do...

I'm on OpenSuse, and when I type "java -version", I get:

```
    java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK  Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_0-b11)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 1.6.0_0-b11, mixed mode)
```

I can't see any references to java requirements for JRuby, though...

As far as RVM, I'm running:

```
rvm 1.2.4 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

I can install other rubies with RVM (1.9.2, 1.8.7, that sort of thing) with no problem, this is the first issue I've ever found.

It doesn't seem to matter WHICH jruby I install, either.  My rvm knows about:

```
# JRuby
jruby-1.2.0
jruby-1.3.1
jruby-1.4.0
jruby[-1.5.6]
jruby-head
```

I don't even get the same errors for each one of them:

For 1.2.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0 I get:

```
Fatal: GCJ (GNU Compiler for Java) is not supported by JRuby.
```

Where 1.5.6 and head get me the error I mentioned first.

I WANT to use JRuby with Rails 3, so I'm figuring I want the newest version I can get (which is having the exceptions)

Is there ANYTHING I can do, or am I just doomed to not be able to use RVM for my purposes?

### EDIT:

I have confirmed that it's not just RVM, it is JRuby that is to blame. To test, I downloaded JRuby without rvm at all, through the website (I chose version 1.6).  I unpacked it as per the instructions, and typed:

```
bin/jruby -v
```

in the extracted directory.

I got the exact same error:

```
jenny@linux-auvv:~/jruby-1.6.0.RC1> bin/jruby -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jruby.Main
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.Main not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.9)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.9)
```

So, still have no clue what's going on, but at least I know now it's a jruby issue, and not an rvm one (though I still WANT it installed through rvm)

### Edit:

So, I tried updating my OpenJDK, and it was no dice, but I found ANOTHER version of OpenJDK (that I didn't have installed) through YAST, and installed THAT one, and suddenly my manually installed jruby works just fine:

```
jenny@linux-auvv:~/jruby-1.6.0.RC1> bin/jruby -v
```

jruby 1.6.0.RC1 (ruby 1.8.7 patchlevel 330) (2011-01-10 769f847) (OpenJDK Client VM 1.6.0_0) [linux-i386-java]

When I type java -version, I even get something different:

```
    jenny@linux-auvv:~/jruby-1.6.0.RC1> java -version
java version "1.6.0_0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.6.2) (suse-0.1.1-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

It even works in RVM, so hooray!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try installing the Sun JRE/JDK.

Or perhaps you could reinstall OpenJDK(probably the easiest way to reset it to being the default on your system).

**Update:**

To change the default java do this. First check which Javas are available:

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

To actually change which one you are using do this:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: I tried reinstalling OpenJDK (I couldn't figure out how to install Sun's .bin file they provided for linux), but I'm still getting the same two errors...Not sure why it's trying to use GCJ for the older stuff (but maybe not for the newer? Wait, no, they're referencing it in the libgcj.so file thingy)  Maybe I can somehow delete it entirely?

Comment: Figured out how to install Sun, didn't change anything either (and when I do java-version, I still see the refernece to OpenJDK). Gonna look into changing which JDK it uses, like JMCO suggests.

Comment: Which os/distribution are you using?

Comment: OpenSuse.  I ended up figuring out that I could use YAST to download the sun JDK (just like I did with OpenJDK), but it still lists OpenJDK under java, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clue is in this:

> Fatal: GCJ (GNU Compiler for Java) is not supported by JRuby.

For whatever reason, your system is configured to fire up GCJ instead of your OpenJDK compiler.  Check the docs on your system for how it handles the case where multiple things can provide the same service name (multiple versions of compilers, for example, or multiple interpreters) and see what you can do to have OpenJDK be the default handler for Java compilation and execution.

Comment: I'm worried...because if it was a system config, then you'd think it would list GCJ when I typed java -version, rather than OpenJDK... I hope it's not a "jruby is configured to prefer the broken JDK" or something like that.  I'll look into it, though.